# Changing Voltage

Tags: electric-circuits, acoustics, voltage, electronics, electrical-engineering

Today I noticed this happening that while my laptop was connected to the charger and there were small voltage fluctuations in my home, I could hear some clear sounds in my earphones (while they were connected to my laptop port). Can someone explain what's the reason behind it?

Comment: was your only evidence of 'voltage fluctuation' from your headphones? this could just be an issue of ground isolation in your ports, but more likely something to do with drivers since most computers isolate the ground for the headphone port. I had this problem once and resetting my drivers solved it, although you might be experiencing unwanted feedback from ground.

Comment: electronics.stackexchange would probably be a better place to ask.